# Finding if it's possible to get to a certain element in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

I was wondering if I, from a certain point in sth like a binary tree, could get to a next certain point.

I should say also, that I don't have a tree structure. I will have just points.
For example (342,124) -> (23420,1324) and the program should say me if it is possible to go from (342,124) to (23420,1324).

My coordinate system template (depthToNode,Node). I just need to know if I can move from a point to point, which those points are linked by exactly the same way, the same values, like in the data structure in the image.

Some explanation:

- The top node is (0, 0)
- Every MOVE increases depthToNode by one; At the same time value of the node decreases by 1 when moving to left or increases by 1 when moving to right.During a MOVE Every node is connected to left and right subnodes. When moving to left - leftNode decreases value node  and Node value can increase by one. Thus basic MOVE can be only (+1, -1) or (+1, +1).

[image: binarytree]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your coordinate system and what your problem specifically is? Also, the above structure is related to a binary search tree, but it's not a true BST because it's not a tree. I think it's more of a "binary search DAG."

Comment: Did my solution answer your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it appeared first to me like a problem that can be solved using Breadth First Search or Depth First Search algorithms.

After having a closer look at the problem - I noticed that there is a clear pattern that can be turned into equation. I focused on the fact that left subnode has value Node-1 and and right subnode has value Node+1.
So thinking in terms of points we can have points (a, b) and (c, d):

For (a, b) and (c, d) where c>=a

You have N=c-a consecutive operations.
There are two types of operations L= -1 and R=+1.

The solution exists if there is l and r that:

(L*l + R*r)=d-b where l+r==N and l >= 0, r >= 0, both int.

So:
(L*(N-r) + R*r)=d-b

NL-Lr+Rr = d-b

-N+2r=d-b

2r=d-b+N

2r=d-b+c-a

**So in the end:**

If d-b+c-a produce R that is even and greater or equal to zero (0, 2, 4 ... ) = there is a path.

**Lets try it:**

(0, 0) -> (3, 1):   1 - 0 + 3 - 0 = 2 (path exists, cause it is 0, 2, 4...)

(2, 0) -> (4, -4): -4 - 0 + 4 - 2 = -2 (path does not exists).

Comment: I consolidated two posts into one. Did this approach work and answers your question?